# Use the Node.js + PostgreSQL to get by id

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

I am trying to write an application with Node.js & PostgreSQL, currently I faced a problem in get by id, below is my code

```
app.get('/monsters/:id', (request, response, next) => {
  const { id } = req.params;
  pool.query('select * from monsters where id = $1', [id], (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }else {
      response.json(res.rows);
    }
  });
});
```

it supposed to get the id I typed and return the value I stored in database with a table name called monster, however it just kept returning a blank object {}, I found the problem may because of the $1 part since my atom seemed not able to recognize $, what can I do to fix this problem or is there other way to write this instruction? Thank you!

Comment: If you replace the `$1` with your actual ID, does it work?

Comment: Since you are working with a SQL database for Node.js, is there a reason you are not using ORMs like Sequelize.js? Unless you are trying to achieve some crazy queries, I think it would be a lot simpler for your understanding and code.

Otherwise, try wrapping the `$1` in a string in case it is not comparing correctly like `'select * from monsters where id = "$1"'`